# application crash after i try to login

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication

I tried to login to my application and this is the error that I got:

```
08-28 07:57:31.450: E/JSON(1047): <br />n<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.  
in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\API\include\DB_connect.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br />n<br />n<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.  
in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\API\include\DB_connect.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br />nNo database selectedn
08-28 07:57:31.450: E/JSON Parser(1047): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

It looks like it didn't succeed in connecting to the DB but I don't understand why.

In addition this is my `index.php` file which is located in `xampp/htdocs/api`:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') {
// get tag
$tag = $_POST['tag'];

// include db handler
require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// response Array
$response = array("tag" => $tag, "success" => 0, "error" => 0);

// check for tag type
if ($tag == 'login') {
    // Request type is check Login
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // check for user
    $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);
    if ($user != false) {
        // user found
        // echo json with success = 1
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
        $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
        $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // user not found
        // echo json with error = 1
        $response["error"] = 1;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Incorrect email or password!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else if ($tag == 'register') {
    // Request type is Register new user
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // check if user is already existed
    if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {
        // user is already existed - error response
        $response["error"] = 2;
        $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed";
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // store user
        $user = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $password);
        if ($user) {
            // user stored successfully
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
            $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
            $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
            $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
            $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user failed to store
            $response["error"] = 1;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Error occured in Registartion";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
     } else {
            echo "Invalid Request";
     }
      } else {
             echo "Access Denied";
            }
 ?>
```

This is the `config.php` file:

```
<?php

    define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
    define("DB_USER", "root");
    define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
    define("DB_DATABASE", "dbapp");
?>
```

The `db_connect.php` file:

```
<?php

class DB_Connect {

    // constructor
    function __construct() {

    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {
        // $this->close();
    }

    // Connecting to database
    public function connect() {
        require_once 'config.php';
        // connecting to mysql
        $con = mysql_connect('DB_HOST', 'DB_USER', 'DB_PASSWORD');
        // selecting database
        mysql_select_db('DB_DATABASE');

        // return database handler
        return $con;
    }

    // Closing database connection
    public function close() {
        mysql_close();
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Several problems:

1. Get rid of **mysql_*** functions, they are deprecated and no longer be maintained, use mysqli or PDO extensions
2. You are using constants as strings, so mysql_connect cannot connect to any server called `DB_HOST`
3. You aren't importing `config.php` file so `db_connect.php` don't know about the constants

So, the db_connect.php will be something like this (i'll use ***mysql_** functions, but you should use mysqli functions at least, i can rewrite your class using PDO if needed)

```
<?php

require('config.php); // <--- Added require

class DB_Connect {

    // constructor
    function __construct() {

    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {
        // $this->close();
    }

    // Connecting to database
    public function connect() {
        require_once 'config.php';
        // connecting to mysql
        $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD); //<---- REMOVED '
        // selecting database
        mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);

        // return database handler
        return $con;
    }

    // Closing database connection
    public function close() {
        mysql_close();
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: when i try to add require('config.php); all my screen become grey, you sure the code is correct?

Comment: It depends on your config.php are. The code i wrote consider the `config.php` is in the same directory that `db_connect.php` if not just change the path. And tur php errors on (the error you describe gives you a fatal error i guess)

Answer (score 0):

i found the reason for that, in the DB_connect file i should insert the parameters directly instead to get it from config.php file

in the first it was :

```
public function connect() {
    require_once 'config.php';
    // connecting to mysql
    $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    // selecting database
    mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);

    // return database handler
    return $con;
}
```

and its should be:

```
public function connect() {
    require_once 'config.php';
    // connecting to mysql
    $con = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '');
    // selecting database
    mysql_select_db('dbapp');

    // return database handler
    return $con;
}
```

Comment: That's wrong, you only need to import file `config.php` using `require` and use it on your file